# Warning message about Git on IE 11: "a website wants to open web content using this program on your computer"

Tags: windows

This is something that happened while using IE 11 on Win 7 x64. Not sure if it matters but IE is running in "Protected Mode".

I was posting a support request for a software that I use at that software vendors site and clicked on the browse button to add a screenshot (from my desktop) to the request. When Windows Explorer opened, the following message was displayed:

[image: git warning]

I had submitted the other support request to the same vendor's site earlier the same day, also with a screenshot, without receiving any warning like this.

**Update:** Not sure if it matters but the vendor, in this case, was Reallusion (a maker of animation software). They do not provide any software through git to regular end users and I had already attached a screenshot to another ticket on their site earlier this same day (without this kind of message).

Would anyone know why this error happens and if it is related to browsing the file system from IE?

Also is there a way to find out if this notification actually originates from the currently browsed website (or if it was caused by some other process and just coincidental that the message popped up when it did)?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it often happens IE does not fare well with certificates of other authorities. Basically your IE does not recognize "The Git Development Community" as a valid issuer of certificates.

If you are still unsure, you could do a research on the community, or try to upload the screen shot the same way you did it earlier.

Using an already proven and working way to do something is always preferred, but I would not worry too much over this particular instance.